# why sizeof unsigned char array[10] is 10

Tags: c, sizeof

The size of char is 1 byte, and wikipedia says:

> sizeof is used to calculate the size of any datatype, measured in the
>   number of bytes required to represent the type.

However, i can store **11 bytes** in `unsigned char array[10]` 0..10 but when i do `sizeof(array)` i get **10 bytes**. can someone explain explain this behavior?

note: i have tried this on int datatype, the sizeof(array) was 40, where i expect it to be 44.

Comment: No, the valid indices will be `0-9`.

Comment: You can store 11 things in 10 boxes? That's a nice trick...

Comment: That's a dangerous trick. The eleventh box is called buffer overflow.

Comment: The 11th box is a secret compartment in the array where you can hide valuable things, but every now and again the RAM goblins will find it and eat your valuable things. Also sometimes when you put things there, other variables in your program will get jealous and change their value.

Comment: I bet John Skeet can store 12 things in ten boxes..

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> However, i can store 11 bytes in unsigned char array[10]

No, you cannot: 10 is not a valid index of `array[10]`. Arrays are indexed from zero to size minus one.

According to C99 Standard

> **6.5.3.4.3** When [`sizeof` operator is] applied to an operand that has type `char`, `unsigned char`, or `signed char`, (or a qualified version thereof) the result is 1.

That is why the result is going to be ten on all standard-compliant platform.

Comment: +1. `array[10]` has ten slots. 0 through 9. In `C` you can go beyond bounds, but you really shouldn't...

Comment: "but you shouldn't" doesn't quite cut it.  You cannot without breaking something else.  The OS will either terminate your program or you will be messing up memory that you will likely want to use for its original purpose later.

Comment: @xaxxon: Or, worse yet, nothing will go wrong (until you demonstrate the program to an important customer).

Comment: @xaxxon: “Should not” is the correct phrasing. Actually, the C standard uses the words “shall not” to express restrictions, which is very close. Writing to `array[10]` breaks a rule (so you shall not do it), but it is sometimes physically possible (so you can do it). Furthermore, we have had questions on Stack Overflow from people who think you cannot do it asking why they are not getting an error when they try. So we really have to explain that you **can**, but you **shall not**, and bad things may happen if you try.

Comment: @EricPostpischil sometimes technically correct is the worst kind.

Comment: @xaxxon: It is not just about technically correct. As I explained, people get the wrong idea from the word “cannot”. Explaining correctly is required to convey the concepts correctly.

Comment: @EricPostpischil So [this](http://i.imgur.com/pkIbjnO.jpg) is what the C standard says?

Comment: @Kevin Thou shalt not. Right. Such as in "Thou shalt not steal" and "Thou shalt not murder". With similiar consequences.

Answer (score 7):

No, the valid indices will be `0-9` not `0-10`, it will store `10` elements not `11`, so the result of `sizeof` is correct. Accessing beyond index `9` will be out of bounds and [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), the relevant section of the [`C99 draft standard`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) is `6.5.6/8`, which covers pointer arithmetic:

> [...] If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the behavior is undefined. If the result points one past the last element of the array object, it shall not be used as the operand of a unary * operator that is evaluated.

Unlike the C++ standard which explicitly states an `array has N elements numbered 0 to N-1` it looks like you need to dig into the examples for a similar statement in the C standard. In the `C99 draft standard` section `6.5.2.1/4`, the example is:

```
int x[3][5];
```

and it goes on to state:

> Here x is a 3 x 5 array of ints; more precisely, x is an array of three element objects, each of which is an array of five ints.

Comment: Is it undefined behavior? AFAIK using square brackets to dereference a pointer is well defined, even for negative indices. Does the compiler treat `char array[10]` differently to `char *pointer`?

Comment: @WayneUroda If you think it's well defined, then what do you think it's defined to be?

Comment: C99 6.5.2.1: `The deﬁnition of the subscript operator []
is that E1[E2] is identical to (*((E1)+(E2))).`

Comment: @WayneUroda: The C standard defines pointer arithmetic only within arrays and to one element beyond the last element of the array. Any other pointer arithmetic (and hence any subscripting) is undefined. The position one element beyond the last element may be used in arithmetic, but it may not be dereferenced. Per C 2011 (N1570) 6.5.6 8: “If the result points one past the last element of the array object, it shall not be used as the operand of a unary `*` operator that is evaluated.” (Note: For pointer arithmetic, a single object acts as an array of one element.)

Comment: @WayneUroda: Yes but accessing an element beyond the bounds of an array is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @WayneUroda Well, yeah, but that only defines the behaviour of `E1[E2]` when the behaviour of `*(E1+E2)` is defined. Which in this case, it is not.

Comment: Thanks :) However, what if I did the following: `(&array[9])[1]` - is this legal C? `&array[9]` yields a char* pointing to the last element of the defined memory. `[1]` then performs `*(address+1)` on that - sure, the memory doesn't belong to the original array, but the *behavior* will always be the same in my understanding. Is that an incorrect understanding? Does using the address of (`&`) operator change the rules here?

Comment: @WayneUroda: `(&array[9])+1` is legal; it points to one past the last element of `array`. Dereferencing it is not legal. In the C model, there simply is no object there, so C does not define what happens when you access an object that does not exist in its model.

Comment: @WayneUroda What do you mean the behaviour will be the same? The behaviour might be that you get a runtime crash, a "random" value", a value from a different variable, or many other things. Which of those it is depends on many factors including the used compiler, optimization settings and where exactly `array` is allocated. It is does not have to be the same between different compilers/platforms (or the same compiler with different settings) and it is certainly not defined behaviour.

Comment: It's not great, and maybe not legal, but is it well defined? I've seen a lot of code in my time that makes use of this kind of thing - eg. the last item in a struct as `char buffer[1]` - this can then be used to access the memory trailing the struct, i.e. the struct simply defines a header on the data. I'm sure I saw this in the linux kernel once.

Comment: By well defined I mean that it always points to the next byte of memory on the system. Accessing that might cause a segfault or other SYSTEM error, but that it not the concern of the C compiler. It's cool, it's `illegal`. I just asked if it was `undefined` - I am not a C standard guru, I don't even know if there is truly a difference between those terms :)

Comment: @WayneUroda: The C standard says nothing about bytes of memory outside of objects. Whether a C implementation treats a write to `array[10]` as a write to a byte just beyond the memory of `array`, wherever it happens to be, is up to the implementation. The C standard says nothing about this. Since it says nothing, an implementation **may** choose to do various things, and it **may** choose to make guarantees to you or not. However, you cannot rely on this behavior based on anything in the C standard.

Comment: @WayneUroda: As a special case, the last member of a struct may be an incomplete array type. See §6.7.2.1 paragraph 16.

Comment: @WayneUroda: The “last item in a struct” you refer to is common C extension to implement a flexible array member. However, this is not merely an arbitrary use of array indexing and memory. When it is used, the structure is allocated with more memory than the core part of the structure. Additional bytes are added to the `malloc` request so that we know the bytes are there beyond the end of the nominal array. This is not defined by the C standard, but it is supported by some C implementations. Also, this extension was obsoleted by C 1999, which provided formal support for this.

Comment: @WayneUroda: To be clear, the declaration `SomeType array[1];` at the end of a struct, when used with additional allocation and indexing beyond the nominal array dimension, is the old extension. The declaration `SomeType array[];` at the end of a struct is the new flexible array member.

Comment: So from the discussion above, using malloc with extra bytes and `char buffer[1]` to access those bytes, if I then write `buffer[3]` for example this is illegal and undefined C. I assume that's why they added the incomplete `char buffer[]` to C99. I have been thus educated. C never stops surprising.

Comment: @WayneUroda: it's the gift that just keeps giving.

Answer (score 1):

```
unsigned char array[10];/*Array of 10 elements*/
```

which means

```
array[0],array[1],array[2],array[3].......array[9]
```

so `sizeof(array)=10` is correct.